# Behavior of Java sockets when closing output stream

Tags: java, sockets

Can someone explain the following behavior in Java sockets:

The general idea is this:

1. Open socket, Obtain I/O streams.
2. Write request, Close out stream
3. Read Response, Close in stream
4. Close socket.

Here's my question / issue.

If I use a `PrintWriter` for output, and then close it, It closes the whole socket, and the subsequent read operation fails miserably.

Instead if I directly use the socket's `shutdownOutput()` method, it correctly closes the output stream channel, while keeping the socket alive.

**Why would closing the `PrintWriter` object take the whole socket down with it?**

Comment: May be you need to flush it before closing.

Comment: have you tried flushing with .flush() on your connections before closing your printwriter to see if the problem doesnt happen?

Comment: @vcetinick That makes no difference. `close()` calls `flush()`.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This may be what your code looks like:

```
Socket socket;
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
pw.close();
```

Now, let's have a look at the description of `getOutputStream()` method of Socket.

> `getOutputStream`
>
> `public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException`
>
> Returns an output stream for this socket.
>   If this socket has an associated channel then the resulting output stream delegates all  of its operations to the channel. If the channel is in non-blocking mode then the output stream's write operations will throw an `IllegalBlockingModeException`.
>
> ***Closing the returned `OutputStream` will close the associated socket.***
>
> Returns:
>
> an output stream for writing bytes to this socket.
>
> Throws:
>
> IOException - if an I/O error occurs when creating the output stream or if the socket is not connected.

from the description above, we know closing the returned `OutputStream` will close the associated socket.

Now, when you close the `PrintWriter`, it'll close the associated `OutputStream` which will close the associated socket.

Comment: RTFM eh? :) 
I guess that explains it thoroughly.Thanks Bloodwolf!

Comment: @Alanmars how to avoid such situation. What if I want to keep the socket open even after closing the OutputStream. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I'm still missing the answer to `why`. "Why would closing the PrintWriter object take the whole socket down with it?"

Answer (score 3):

It is probably because calling the `close()` method of `PrintWriter` is tracing back through the hierarchy and calling the `close()` method of the `SocketOutputStream` as well. As part of the `close()` method for the `SocketOutputStream` it also calls the `close()` method for the `Socket` as well, which would in term close the `SocketInputStream` as well. Calling the `shutdownOutput()` function instead sends any previously written data followed by TCP's normal connection termination sequence. It then disables the output stream.